# AppleScript to read and save website content (API)

Tags: url, safari, applescript

I have an AppleScript to read URLs line by line and open them in Safari. This one:

```
set thePath to (path to desktop as Unicode text) & "sites.txt"
set theFile to (open for access file thePath)
set theContent to (read theFile)
close access theFile

set theURLs to every paragraph of theContent

tell application "Safari"
    repeat with theURL in theURLs
        make new document
        set URL of front document to theURL
        delay 1
        repeat until ((do JavaScript "document.readyState" in front document) is "complete")
            delay 30
        end repeat
        close front document
    end repeat
end tell
```

In this example I work with these URLs - they are really similar to my use case, which I can't share.

http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=True%20Grit&y=1969

http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Avatar&y=2009

This AppleScript works fine for me, but I can't write the content back to txt-file on my desktop, request by request.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set thePath to (path to desktop as text) & "sites.txt"
set outPath to quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "sites content.txt")

set theUrls to every paragraph of (read file thePath)

set myContent to {}
repeat with aURL in theUrls
    set end of myContent to aURL & return
    set pageContent to do shell script "curl " & aURL
    set end of myContent to pageContent & return & return
end repeat

do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (myContent as text) & " >> " & outPath
```

Comment: Sorry, can't post my solution right now. Later i'll try again.

Comment: Happy to help. If I answered your question, accept it by clicking the check mark to let other users know it is no longer open.